# How to Join 2 tables to get 1 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to make a query for this? I have no idea!!

Table 1

```
userID | Name
0001   | Tim
0002   | James
0003   | Bond
0004   | Steve 
0005   | Bill
```

Table 2

```
ProductID | BuyerID | SellerID
00001     | 0001    | ooo4
00002     | 0003    | 0005
00003     | 0001    | 0002
```

How combine these two to:

```
ProductID | Buyer | Seller
00001     | Tim     | Steve
00002     | Bond    | Bill
00003     | Tim     | James
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT  p.ProductID,
        b.Name as Buyer,
        s.Name Seller
FROm    Table2 p LEFT JOIN
        Table1 b    ON  p.BuyerID = b.userID LEFT JOIN
        Table1 s    ON  p.SellerID = s.userID
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e1d7/3)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
   tbl2.ProductID as ProductID, 
   Buyer.Name as Buyer, 
   Seller.Name as Seller
FROM tbl2
   LEFT JOIN tbl1 Buyer ON tbl2.BuyerID = Buyer.userID
   LEFT JOIN tbl1 Seller ON tbl2.BuyerID = Seller.userID
```